# Variable Length of PhysicalAddress

Tags: .net, mac-address

The `PhysicalAddress` (used for MAC addresses) class supports variable-length byte arrays. As far as I know MAC addresses are always 48-bit long.

Is there a reason why the `PhysicalAddress` allows any lenghts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that physical addresses are always 48 bits long is incorrect. [EUI-64 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_Address) are 64 bits long, for instance.